# App is deleted from device when running connectedAndroidTest

Tags: android, gradle

I am doing some instrumented tests on a device which does not have an existing emulator yet.
I am running the test from the command line using:

```
./gradlew connectedStagingDebugAndroidTest
```

The test runs fine, but the app (if already installed) is uninstalled when running the command above.

How can I run an instrumented test from the command line without deleting the app from the device?

FYI: staging is one of the product flavors defined in the gradle.build:

```
productFlavors {
    production {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.app"
    }
    staging {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.app.staging"
    }
}
```

Comment: that's cool. but what's your question?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: Have updated with a more well phrased question. If you down-voted because of this, consider up-voting

Comment: I am experiencing this same issue. Did you find a solution for it?